# How to save segmented images from U-NET segmentation in python?

Tags: python, computer-vision, image-segmentation, opencv

I have trained a U-NET architecture in Python based [this](https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/identification-and-segmentation-of-nuclei-in-cells) link.

After training, I want to save  individually segmented image's (which are currently multiple images) in directory. How do I save these segmented images in python? 
I am using below code to save results.

```
def saveResults(a,b):        
    preds_test = a.predict(b, verbose=1)
    cutoff=0.5
    a = 'C:/Users/ultim\Desktop/Rest/testpredict'
    for i in range(len(preds_test)):
        lab_img = label(preds_test[i] > cutoff)
        for i in range(1, lab_img.max() + 1):
            lab_img[i] = np.array(lab_img[i], dtype=np.uint8)
            cv2.imwrite('a' + i, lab_img[i])
saveResults(modelZ,X_test)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Do you just want to save the segmented images or perform some action on them before saving? Also, what is the problem with this piece of code? be as specific as you can

Comment: I just want to save segmented images and their corresponding labels as image file. I am trying to run the above code but it is not doing anything and I am unable to figure out the error.